# Kuberenets statefull set's Stable Network ID

Tags: kubernetes, dns, coredns

I am running statefulset: `prometheus-stack/prometheus-ps-prometheus` with 3 replicas (`prometheus-ps-prometheus-0`, `prometheus-ps-prometheus-1`, `prometheus-ps-prometheus-2`)

```bash
$ kubectl get statefulsets -n prometheus-stack prometheus-ps-prometheus
NAME                     
prometheus-ps-prometheus

$ kubectl get pods -n prometheus-stack -o wide
NAME                             STATUS    IP
prometheus-ps-prometheus-0       Running   10.17.2.249 
prometheus-ps-prometheus-1       Running   10.17.3.241 
prometheus-ps-prometheus-2       Running   10.17.1.6
```

I have a **headless** service addresing the statefulset:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ptn 
  namespace: prometheus-stack
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports: [...]
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: prometheus
    prometheus: ps-prometheus
```

I am trying to access the statefulset pods using the service DNS. When I address the service DNS I get correct IPs of the pods, but when I try to access the pods using the IPs I get `error`:

What am I doing wrong? How can I access the pods using the DNS?

```bash
$ dig ptn.prometheus-stack.svc.cluster.local

; <<>> DiG 9.18.13 <<>> ptn.prometheus-stack.svc.cluster.local
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; WARNING: .local is reserved for Multicast DNS
;; You are currently testing what happens when an mDNS query is leaked to DNS
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 43817
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
; COOKIE: ae0111659717eacd (echoed)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ptn.prometheus-stack.svc.cluster.local.        IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ptn.prometheus-stack.svc.cluster.local. 30 IN A 10.17.1.6
ptn.prometheus-stack.svc.cluster.local. 30 IN A 10.17.3.241
ptn.prometheus-stack.svc.cluster.local. 30 IN A 10.17.2.249

;; Query time: 4 msec
;; SERVER: 10.96.0.10#53(10.96.0.10) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Wed Jan 31 19:28:51 UTC 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 241
```

```bash
$ dig prometheus-ps-prometheus-0.ptn.prometheus-stack.svc.cluster.local

; <<>> DiG 9.18.13 <<>> prometheus-ps-prometheus-0.ptn.prometheus-stack.svc.cluster.local
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; WARNING: .local is reserved for Multicast DNS
;; You are currently testing what happens when an mDNS query is leaked to DNS
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 20283
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
; COOKIE: 7dfbe83a77ee64ef (echoed)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;prometheus-ps-prometheus-0.ptn.prometheus-stack.svc.cluster.local. IN A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
cluster.local.          10      IN      SOA     ns.dns.cluster.local. hostmaster.cluster.local. 1706727875 7200 1800 86400 30

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 10.96.0.10#53(10.96.0.10) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Wed Jan 31 19:29:31 UTC 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 199
```

Comment: Can you post your StatefulSet manifest?